# Wrong post_status notice after wp_insert_post_data

Tags: filters, post-status

I'm developing a plugin that checks the post content before publishing. If the content doesn't contain specific information, it is saved as draft instead. For this functionality I use the *wp_insert_post_data* filter:

```
function sl_filter_handler( $data , $postarr )
{
    //Is the post going to be published?
    if($data['post_status'] == 'publish')
    {   
        $postIsValid = true;

        //Do some check on the content
        //...

        if(!$postIsValid)
            $data['post_status'] = 'draft';
    }
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'sl_filter_handler', '99', 2 );
```

Everythings work fine, but I get a wrong notification, if the post is saved as draft by the filter:

[image]

Where is my mistake? Have I to use [wp_transition_post_status](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status)? If so, where should the function call be added?

Comment: Can you please fix the broken image?

Comment: My browser shows the image. Here is the direct link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7ZHI.png Does that work?